# Error : Unable to import package 'kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout'

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have a problem with this simple code i can't import the wanted package

i've tried to copy head codes of some kivy projects but it doesn't work

```
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import MDSeperator kivymd.card.MDSeperator


NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
     #   drawer_logo: "mercedes.jpg"


    Button:
        text: "i'm happy, what about you !"
```

this is the error : Unable to import package 'kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout'

Answer (score 2):

```
# :import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
# :import MDSeparator kivymd.card
```

include these in the kivy file instead

and incldue these in the main file:

```
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer, NavigationLayout
from kivymd.card import MDSeparator
```

Answer (score 0):

All widgets that usually used in kv-lang are automatically added to Factory. You don't need to #:import them. Remove all your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the KivyMD package are you using.

NavigationLayout only exist in DEV package.

RELEASE PACKAGE:

[image: RELEASE 0.104.1]

MASTER BRANCH
[image: Master Branch]

Comment: This is not really an answer. Consider commenting on the question to gain more insight.

Comment: I had a similar issue just two weeks ago and I shared the things I found so thought might be good to look at. Also, I am commenting on the question as well if you take a look "Which version of the KivyMD package are you using. ?"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
```