# I don't understand the error message in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use kivymd using this code :

```
    from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import NavigationLayout
from kivymd.card import MDSeparator


class MyApp(App):
    theme_cls=ThemeManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyApp()
    m.run()
```

but im getting this error :

```
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.navigationdrawer'
>>>
```

This is my kv file :

```
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import MDSeparator kivymd.card

NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
<Button>:
    text: "Hey"
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58118098/error-unable-to-import-package-kivymd-navigationdrawer-navigationlayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EXPLANATION -- PLEASE READ: 
You're using some code that was made for an older version of KivyMD. In new versions, most widgets have been moved to the `kivymd.uix` folder, so you would change `#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout` to `#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout` (and similar for all other widgets. BUT, all KivyMD widgets are automatically recognized in `kv` files as long as you have `from kivymd.app import MDApp` in your `main.py` file. (In Python you would still need to write `from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer` or whatever if you need to access the class in Python).

SOLUTION:

`main.py`:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MyApp(MDApp):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyApp()
    m.run()
```

`my.kv`:

```
NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
    Button:
        text: "Hey"
```

Comment: So if they moved it to different folder, how are we supposed to know which folder what files are in? Coz I'm watching some a year old tuts and I'm continuously running into such above mentioned errors and if I fix them as per your instruction I'm getting ValueErrors and that I've to see the HeaTTheatR's github repo for #api-breaking-changes !!

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck here too, but I went to **C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\kivyMD** and I realized that NavigationDrawer is in **uix/** folder. So the import should be something like this

> from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer

. It worked for me tho. Good luck! xD

here is a simple .kv code

```
Screen:

    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Gray"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
```